# Manage user project permissions

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I have just created a Visual Studio Online account and have added a new user.

**How do I manage project permissions for that user?**

I have been through every available page when logged in as Administrator and I cannot find anything.  The only thing I can do is add the user as a member to the new project.

Added new user:

[image]

Added user as member on new project:

[image]

Example of missing permissions:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After adding it to users for team project permissions you need to click on Settings icon on top right. [image]

Then select the Team project on the left and then click "Manage project security and group membership" and then add user to one of the VSO groups shown below in the image.

[image]

Comment: Yep, most undiscoverable icon ever.