# Permit a member to add more members to the team

Tags: azure-devops

I am an admin to a lot many projects. I have permissions to add members to any particular Project. But if I would like to promote a member as a Project Admin, I would like him to have permissions to add new members to the project.

I have added this person as a member of Project Administrator. Though he can now see the `+` symbol to add a member in `Dashboard`, it says he doesn't have permissions to add a member. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you talking about the **team member** dashboard? Could the user add member through security page?

Comment: Hi Anoop K. Prabhu, any update on this issue, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are talking about the team member dashboard to add member to the default team.

[image]

- First double confirm you have promoted the member as a Project Admin
  correctly, you could refer this question:
  [Manage user project permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703078/manage-user-project-permissions)
- Check the user is adding to VSTS for the first time or not. If it's,
  need [add account users for VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-account-users-from-user-hub?toc=/vsts/security/toc.json&bc=/vsts/security/breadcrumb/toc.json) first. For this, the member will
  need [VSTS project collection administrator or account owner
  permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/faq-add-delete-users#find-owner). However he is just a project admin, this maybe why he doesn't have permission.

---

Besides you could also add/manager members of other team, choose the gear cog
 and **Security** from the menu.  Then find the team on the left pane
 of the **security** page and select it. In the right pane, choose the
 **Members** view (next to **Permissions**), and then you will see a green plus symbol and the **Add...** button.

[image]

More details please refer this tutorial--[Add team project members in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-team-members-vs)